# Using conditionals to set tag parameters

Tags: conditionals, parse-order, advanced-conditionals

I have this opening low search result tag

```
{exp:low_search:results
  {if segment_2}query="{segment_2}"{/if}
  group_id="7"
  limit="4"
  paginate="bottom"
}
```

I wanted to do more checks on segment_2 before deciding if I should set query param(checking if the segment is for pagination such as P1 or P4).

```
{exp:low_search:results
    {if segment_2 == '' OR {exp:segment_search keyword="/^P\d+$/" segments="2" regex="yes"}}{if:else}query="{segment_2}"{/if}
     group_id="7"
     limit="4"
     paginate="bottom"
}
```

However, I don't think this will work. I think it has something to do with the parse order where you can't set complex conditionals inside a tag.

If so, is there an alternative way to set the query param?

UPDATE: The reason I am asking is because the code below does not work

```
{if {segment_2} == '' OR {exp:segment_search keyword="/^P\d+$/" segments="2" regex="yes"}}
    {exp:low_search:results
        {if segment_1 == "foo"}group_id="6"{/if}
        {if segment_1 == "bar"}group_id="7"{/if}
        limit="4"
        paginate="bottom"}
{if:else}
    {exp:low_search:results
        query="{segment_2}"
        {if segment_1 == "foo"}group_id="6"{/if}
        {if segment_1 == "bar"}group_id="7"{/if}
        limit="4"
        paginate="bottom"}
{/if}
```

I always get a `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ELSE` in the code where I don't set the `query` param.

Comment: I'd suggest you edit this question to take Low Search out of the equation. It's a question about parse order and conditionals rather than LS, as the same issue would occur using the native channel:entries tag. Or any other tag, for that matter.

Comment: @Low Changed the tags and title

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So yeah. Parse order. I take it you've seen [this pdf](http://gotolow.com/parse-order). If not, take a look, study it well.

What you need is for the opening tag to be in order **before you hit stage 5**: the parsing of module/plugin tags. In order to do that, you can only use **simple conditionals** in combination with early parsed global variables and preload replace variables. Native early parsed vars are limited, so go and get the super useful (and free) [Mo' Variables](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/mo-variables) to get more useful early parsed stuff.

Once installed, you can use `{if paginated}{/if}` as a simple conditional. Just beware you don't use any `AND` or `OR` operators, nor use `{if:else}` in your conditionals, because that will turn it into an advanced one, and will be parsed too late for your use.

First of all, this: `{if {segment_2} == ''}` is an advanced conditional. The simple syntax is `{if segment_2 == ''}`. Using tags in conditionals, like you do with the `{exp:segment_search}` tag, means the conditional is advanced, too. So, avoid.

Here's my take, using preload replace vars and **simple conditionals only**.

```
{!-- Don't set the query param if there is no query --}
{if segment_2 == ''}
    {preload_replace:pre_query=''}
{/if}

{!-- Don't set the query param for non-query paginated pages --}
{if segment_3 == ''}
    {if paginated}
        {preload_replace:pre_query=''}
    {/if}
{/if}

{!-- Determine group ID based on segment 1 --}
{if segment_1 == 'foo'}
    {preload_replace:pre_group_id="6"}
{/if}

{if segment_1 == 'bar'}
    {preload_replace:pre_group_id="7"}
{/if}

{!-- Default Preload Replace vars --}
{preload_replace:pre_query='query="{segment_2}"'}
{preload_replace:pre_group_id="6|7"}

{!-- Here comes the Results tag --}
{exp:low_search:results {pre_query} group_id="{pre_group_id}" limit="4"}
  ...
{/exp:low_search:results}
```

So, note that I don't use any conditionals in the tag itself. Everything is done using simple conditionals and preload replace vars. Keeps things nice and clean. And I haven't even mentioned [Switchee](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/switchee) yet...

Answer (score 2):

You problem is you're trying to do a complex conditional within the tag parameters, that's not possible.

Here's a good article regarding parsing conditionals within tags:
http://johndwells.com/blog/expressionengine-parse-order-advanced-conditionals-as-tag-parameters

As you state, the problem is simple conditionals versus complex conditionals.

The problem with your second code:

```
{if {segment_2} == '' OR {exp:segment_search keyword="/^P\d+$/" segments="2" regex="yes"}}
    {exp:low_search:results
        {if segment_1 == "foo"}group_id="6"{/if}
        {if segment_1 == "bar"}group_id="7"{/if}
        limit="4"
        paginate="bottom"}
{if:else}
    {exp:low_search:results
        query="{segment_2}"
        {if segment_1 == "foo"}group_id="6"{/if}
        {if segment_1 == "bar"}group_id="7"{/if}
        limit="4"
        paginate="bottom"}
{/if}
```

...Is that you won't be able to have the opening tag in a separate conditional to the closing tag - EE parses conditionals at a separate stage to tags. It's not linear (working from top to bottom).

This *may* work:

```
{if {segment_2} == '' OR {exp:segment_search keyword="/^P\d+$/" segments="2" regex="yes"}}
    {exp:low_search:results
        {if segment_1 == "foo"}group_id="6"{/if}
        {if segment_1 == "bar"}group_id="7"{/if}
        limit="4"
        paginate="bottom"}

        {title}

    {/exp:low_search:results}
{if:else}
    {exp:low_search:results
        query="{segment_2}"
        {if segment_1 == "foo"}group_id="6"{/if}
        {if segment_1 == "bar"}group_id="7"{/if}
        limit="4"
        paginate="bottom"}

        {title}

    {/exp:low_search:results}
{/if}
```

...Where each tag pair is contained within the same conditional.

There's an additional problem in your revised conditional that is showing a parse error:

```
{if {segment_2} == '' OR {exp:segment_search keyword="/^P\d+$/" segments="2" regex="yes"}}
```

If there is no keyword, that tag will return an empty string, resulting in your conditional looking like this prior to EE parsing it: `{if {segment_2} == '' OR }`

...Which will result in the parse error.  This is safer:

```
{if {segment_2} == '' OR '{exp:segment_search keyword="/^P\d+$/" segments="2" regex="yes"}'}
```

With the quotes, it can be parsed correctly as `{if {segment_2} == '' OR ''}`

Or how I'd approach it, by including in an embed and doing all the conditionals in the parent:

```
{if {segment_2} == '' OR {exp:segment_search keyword="/^P\d+$/" segments="2" regex="yes"}}
    {embed=template-group/search-results group_id="{if segment_1 == "foo"}6{/if}{if segment_1 == "bar"}7{/if}" query=""}
{if:else}
    {embed=template-group/search-results group_id="{if segment_1 == "foo"}6{/if}{if segment_1 == "bar"}7{/if}" query='query="{segment_2}"'}
{/if}
```

And in the embed template:

```
    {exp:low_search:results
        group_id="{embed:group_id}"
        {embed:query}
        limit="4"
        paginate="bottom"}

        {title}

    {/exp:low_search:results}
```

Note: for the first embed, query will be an empty string which is fine to pass as a parameter.

Comment: Setting the query to a blank string is wrong. It will output different results from not setting the query param at all. That is why you see in my code that I am checking if I should set query param or not. Otherwise, I could simply do query="{if segment_2}{segment_2}{/if}"

Comment: I've amended the embed example to accommodate this.