# Low Search - Showing all items and Pagination

Tags: low-search

I have these simple code using low search

```
{exp:low_search:results
    {if segment_2}query="{segment_2}"{/if}
    limit="4"
    paginate="bottom"
}
```

This normally works for the search except when I want to show everything. To do that, I simply need to eliminate the query param

```
{exp:low_search:results
    limit="4"
    paginate="bottom"
}
```

However, here is the problem. What if I paginate through the results? In my case then I would have a pagination link of something like

```
http://www.foo.com/search/P4
```

But if I use the code above

```
{if segment_2}query="{segment_2}"{/if}
```

then it will mistakenly believe that `P4` is a query string.

How should these be handled?

Comment: Based on your previous questions regarding Low search and parsing you already have the answer. You're using segment_search already, so use it outside the parameters with a negative conditional or negative regx to identify if segment_2 is a paginated segment. e.g. {if {exp:segment_search keyword="/P\d+/" segments="2" regex="yes"}}pages{if:else}not{/if}

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parse Order - Query Param](http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/11826/parse-order-query-param)

Comment: Hi did you figure out how to fix it?

Comment: @vIsual follow the Parse Order - Query Param link